# Optimized approach to finding which pairs of numbers another number falls between?

Tags: python, algorithm, search, data-structures

Given a list of regions on a line:

```
regions = [(10,25), (18, 30), (45, 60), ...] # so on so forth, regions can be overlapping, of variable size, etc.
```

I want to know which regions a point X belongs to:

```
x = 23
find_regions(regions, x) # ==> [(10, 25), (18, 30)]
```

I know naively (and my current implementation) we can just search in O(n), but a more dramatic use case with thousands of regions (*and thousands of look up points, really, is the motivator*) justifies investigating a faster approach than this:

```
regions = [(start, end) for (start, end) in regions if start < x and x < end]
```

I would hazard a guess that someone has solved this problem before...but I'm not sure how it would be best accomplished. Thoughts?

Comment: Why would `find_regions(regions, x)` return `[(10, 20), (22, 30)]`?

Comment: forgot to update that sample to the original definition (18, 30)

Comment: I still don't get it. In what sense `23` "belongs" to the region `(10, 20)`?

Comment: Turns out I messed it up for both

Comment: And you have a typo in the `regions = ` line as well.

Comment: Do you need to find all regions in the list of possible regions for which the input falls between the min and max? That will increase the computational burden somewhat - no algorithm can rule out a range without checking its upper bound if the lower bound qualifies, or vice versa. I can't answer this myself except to say that if you have monotonically increasing lower bounds you can benefit at least somewhat from a binary search algorithm to find the ranges that might qualify. But any algorithm would need to define the correct behavior when multiple ranges cover the input.

Comment: It would be to find all of the ranges - I imagined using some kind of binary search trace to find the min/max (so two different searches on regions sorted by min and by max) would be a less naive approach

Comment: @zaczap Do you need it for multiple queries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the exact job [interval trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) were designed to do. Googling `Python interval tree` turns up an existing library called [Banyan](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Banyan) that implements them, though I can't speak for its reliability, and it doesn't seem to be actively developed. You could also implement your own interval tree.

The preprocessing time to construct an interval tree from a list of N intervals is in O(Nlog(N)), and unlike some of the other answers, it only takes O(N) space, regardless of how much the intervals overlap. The time to figure out how many intervals overlap a given point is in O(M+log(N)), where M is the number of intervals containing the point.

Banyan interval tree demo, pulled from the [PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Banyan):

```
>>> t = SortedSet([(1, 3), (2, 4), (-2, 9)], updator = OverlappingIntervalsUpdator)
>>>
>>> print(t.overlap_point(-5))
[]
>>> print(t.overlap_point(5))
[(-2, 9)]
>>> print(t.overlap_point(3.5))
[(-2, 9), (2, 4)]
>>>
>>> print(t.overlap((-10, 10)))
[(-2, 9), (1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The only changes I would make to your list comprehension would be to make it a `generator`, to shorten the comparison to `start < x < end`, and to optionally call `next()` if you only need one:

```
>>> regions = [(10,25), (18, 30), (45, 60)]
>>> x = 23
>>> next((start, end) for (start, end) in regions if start < x < end)
(18, 30)
```

Note also that your comparison `start > x and x < end` had a backwards `>`. Should be `start < x and x < end`. That fix is included in my answer

---

Edit: seeing comments and answers about binary search makes me realize I'm of course dead wrong about the lack of room for improvement. That said, I'll still keep this answer around for the sake of marginally improved comparison and short-circuit via `next()`. But my improvements are minuscule compared to those by binary searching.

I've made your search linearly faster. Binary is logarithmic.

Answer (score 0):

If the regions are overlapping, just sort the regions and do a binary search.

If regions are overlapping, for every overlapped region calculate list of overlapping regions and store them as a list. Then do a binary search.

Eg: (1,10),(5,15)
Convert to

```
(1,4), (5,10), (11, 15)
  |       |        |
(1,10) (1,10)  (5,15)
          |
       (5,15)
```

That is, link (5,10) to the regions it belongs to.

Note: These are just clues, you need to do a little more work.

Comment: Sorting itself is O(NlogN), whereas his original idea is O(N). But in the long run, pre-sorting approach would beat the O(N^M) approach.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you split everything into non-overlapping *elementary intervals*, so that each elementary interval is either completely covered or completely outside any given interval.  Then you create a map from elementary intervals to given intervals.  Because the elementary intervals do not overlap, you find the matching one easily using binary search.  From that you can look up which actual intervals are mapped to it.
Initial sorting is O(N log N), Building the map is O(N), the final look-up is O(log N), because of the binary search.  The number of elementary intervals is smaller than 2*N.

Here's a rough implementation of this.  Not sure about the case where the search point exactly hits end interval end.

```
class IntervalFinder():
    elem_list = [] # the borders of the elementary interval
    elem_sets = [] # the actual intervals mapped to each elementary
    def __init__( self, intervals ):
        # sort the left ends
        a = sorted( intervals )
        # sort the right ends
        b = sorted( intervals, key=lambda x : x[1] )
        ia = 0 # index into a
        start = a[0][0] # the start of the elementary interval

        # the set of actual intervals covering the
        # current elementary
        current = set()
        for xb in b:
            while ia < len(a) and a[ia][0] < xb[1]:
                stop = a[ia][0]
                # an elementary interval ends here
                # because a new interval starts
                if stop > start:
                    self.elem_sets.append( set( current ) )
                    self.elem_list.append(start)
                    start = stop
                current.add( a[ia] )
                ia += 1

            if start < xb[1]:                    
                self.elem_sets.append(set(current))
                self.elem_list.append(start)
                start = xb[1]

            current.remove( xb )

        self.elem_sets.append(set())
        self.elem_list.append(start)


    def find( self, a ):
        k = bisect.bisect( self.elem_list, a ) - 1
        if k<0:
            return set()
        # if its exactly on the border
        # it belongs to both the right and the left
        if a == self.elem_list[k]: 
            h = set(self.elem_sets[k])
            return h.union( self.elem_sets[k-1] )
        else:
            return self.elem_sets[k]

intervals = [ ( 1, 10), (5, 15), (10, 20), (5, 30) ]

ifind = IntervalFinder(intervals)
for x in [0, 4,5,9,10,11, 20, 25, 30, 35]:
    print( x, ifind.find(x) )
```